# OpenGL ES - vector uniforms not found - only Matrices work

Tags: android, opengl-es

I try to make an app with OpenGLES 2. There are 2 devices for testing.
Unfortunately there seems to be a difference between both.

I have the following "basic" shader code for testing:

```
// vertex shader

uniform mat4 uVMatrix;          // View Matrix
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;          // perspective Matrix
uniform vec3 uLight1Pos;        // LightPos

attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aColor;

varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    vColor = aColor;
    mat4 MVPMatrix = uPMatrix * uVMatrix;   
    gl_Position = MVPMatrix * aPosition;
}

// fragment shader

uniform mat4 uVMatrix;
uniform vec3 uLight1Pos;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec3 vPosition;

void main() { 
    vec3 light2Pos = uLight1Pos;    
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

The problem is, some uniforms can't be found.

I attach and link the shader as usual but checking the IDs like:

```
uVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uVMatrix");
uPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uPMatrix");
uLight1PosHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uLight1Pos");
```

I get different values.
On my Galaxy S1 it is **2, 1, 3** (so all valid values - even though a weird order).
On my Galaxy S3 it is **0, 1, -1** (so the last one can not be found).

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to declare uniform differently on a S3 (Mali GPU)?
I realized that I have to "use" the uniforms in order to get a reference. That is the reason why I wrote *vec3 light2Pos = uLight1Pos;* If I dont do this, I also get no reference on the S1.

Thank you for your help!

Tobias

**- EDIT -**

Weird enough, I tried to change the uniform of the vertex shader from *vec3* to a *mat4*:

```
uniform mat4 uLight1Pos;
mat4 lPos = uLight1Pos;
```

It appears that **matrices work fine** and I can get a handle for it when using a matrix. How comes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "use" doesn't have a contribution to the output fragcolor. You just proved the S3 has a better compiler than the S1 for removing dead code.

Comment: Ah, I see. So even though I "used" them they were not really used and removed. Thanks a lot. Looks like it was simply my fault! :D

Answer (score 1):

GLSL compilers tend to eliminate unused uniforms which don't contribute to the result. This behavior is in compliance with OpenGL specification.

In your case, the compiler is allowed to eliminate the dead line `vec3 light2Pos = uLight1Pos;` rendering the `uLight1Pos` uniform useless.